# Should conditional wrap call or code?

Tags: coding-style, conditional-statements

Currently trying to refactor some legacy code and I find myself stumbling across the same situation over and over again.  I have a very large function that I want to use extract method on for several blocks.  Many times the blocks I aim to extract are wrapped entirely in a conditional.  From a style / best practice standpoint, does it make sense to leave the **conditional wrapping the new method call**, or extract the **conditional wrapping code** into the new method.  Can you explain the pros / cons?

i.e. do you prefer

A)

```
Big_function() {
    <...>
    If (conditional) {
        Small_function();
    }
    <...>
}

Small_function() {
    Code
}
```

Or B)

```
Big_function() {
    <...>
    Small_function();
    <...>
}

Small function() {
    If (conditional) {
        Code
    }
}
```

Maybe this is trivial, but since I see it a lot, thought I would ask.  Let's assume small_function would not be reused in either form, simply used to extract this block.

thanks.

Comment: Depends on whether checking the conditional can reasonably be thought of as part of `smallfunction`, and if not, whether it's economical to rename it `smallfunction_if_condition`. There's no silver bullet for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context.  For each instance, if you have a gut feeling either way, you're probably right.  Just make sure the name of the inner function matches the implied if check, or lack of thereof.

With that concern out of the way, the best thing to do is to put the if inside the inner function, because there is one big complicated outer function and many simple inner functions.  One extra if check inside several small functions will not add much complexity to them individually, whereas adding lots of extra branches into the outer function will meaningfully affect its complexity and readability.

Lastly, there is a slight perf tradeoff to putting the check inside the inner function vs outside.  You can sometimes incur additional costs of calling and returning from the inner function when the if evaluates to false, but on the other hand your outer code can be slightly smaller (fewer instructions).  For this to make any meaningful impact either way, the outer function has to be VERY hot, and you have to be writing in a low-level language.